# How can I continue running with repl after -main instead of exit?

Tags: clojure, leiningen

```
(ns secretary.core)

(defn -main
  [& args]
  (println args "Hello, World!"))
```

## lein run 1 2 3

(1 2 3) Hello, World!

But I want it keep in REPL. Not exit.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
(ns demo.core )

(defn -main
  [& args]
  (println "Got:" args ))
```

with the above code:

```
> lein repl
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: Options -Xverify:none and -noverify were deprecated in JDK 13 and will likely be removed in a future release.
Compiling 2 source files to /home/alan/expr/demo/target/default/class-files
nREPL server started on port 46184 on host 127.0.0.1 - nrepl://127.0.0.1:46184
REPL-y 0.4.3, nREPL 0.6.0
Clojure 1.10.1
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 13+33

demo.core=> (ns demo.core)
nil
demo.core=> (-main 1 2 3)
Got: (1 2 3)

demo.core=> (+ 3 4)
7
demo.core=>
```

So, you start the REPL first, then call a function (even `-main`). You are still in the REPL when finished.

---

P.S.  Although, my personal favorite, is to use the [lein test-refresh](https://github.com/jakemcc/lein-test-refresh)
plugin and write your experiments in unit-test style using your favorite editor.

Comment: And if you want the args passed to `-main` to be strings like they are when doing `lein run 1 2 3`, you can call `(-main "1" "2" "3")` in the REPL instead, but that is a detail.

Comment: Thank you for answer.
But I know this method.
I hope lein have some command to do this.